# writing excel code to database

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to read an excel file and then write the contents of the excel to database. I am able to read the excel and it display below output if I print. 
I would like to know how to separate or split this data to columns in Database and store the data in database. I have a table in DB that can hold the below data if I seperate into columns.

```
//CODE OUTPUT
1.0     Henry       Rey     Staff       IT      Software Engg       New Hire        TigoAdmin       11-Oct-2012     11-Oct-2012     555.0

2.0     Nick        Murry       Staff       IT      Administrator       New Hire        TigoAdmin       11-Oct-2012     11-Oct-2012     555.0
```

// BELOW is the CODE

package com.project.bulk;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class ReadExcelFile {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                String fileName = "C:\\excelFile.xls";
                Vector dataHolder = ReadCSV(fileName);
                printCellDataToConsole(dataHolder);
        }

        public static Vector ReadCSV(String fileName) {
                Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();

                try {
                        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);

                        POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

                        HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

                        HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

                        Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

                        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
                                HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                                Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                                Vector cellStoreVector = new Vector();
                                while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                                        HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                                        cellStoreVector.addElement(myCell);
                                }
                                cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return cellVectorHolder;
        }

        private static void printCellDataToConsole(Vector dataHolder) {

                for (int i = 0; i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
                        Vector cellStoreVector = (Vector) dataHolder.elementAt(i);
                        for (int j = 0; j < cellStoreVector.size(); j++) {
                              HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellStoreVector.elementAt(j);
                              String stringCellValue = myCell.toString();
                              System.out.print(stringCellValue + "\t\t");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                }
        }
}

Comment: You need to learn how to use the `String.split()` method and the JDBC API to communicate with your database.

Comment: @Code-Guru how that could help to insert data in database?

Comment: Since you have a vector that holds the data from the Excel file, you just need the JDBC sentences to insert the data in your tables.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : this is exactly where I am stuck now. Could you please write an example code how to send the vector data to DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how many arguments you will send to the statement, you can create a method to handle it. I'll give you a very basic example, have in mind that this approach can be heavily improved.

```
public void executeSQLUpdate(String sql, List<Object> arguments) {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        con = getConnection(); //a method that returns a java.sql.Connection to your database
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        if (arguments != null) {
            int i = 1;
            for(Object o : arguments) {
                pstmt.setObject(i++, o);
            }
        }
        //method to execute insert, update, delete statements...
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        //handle the error...
    } finally {
        //closing the resources (always in finally block, not in the try!)
        try {
            if (pstmt != null) {
                pstmt.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
}

//calling the method to execute a sql insert statement
public void yourMethodToData(List<Object> arguments) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO YOUR TABLE VALUES(?)";
    executeSQLUpdate(sql, arguments);
}
```

The `Vector` class implements the `List` interface, so you can pass your `Vector` through these methods.

As a side note, you **should not** use a `Vector`, instead use a `List<Object>` implemented with an `ArrayList<Object>`. More info: [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197)